# A construction of the trig functions on the unit circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can anyone shed some light on this picture?

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Circle-trig6.svg

I am not interested in "$\sin$", "$\cos$", or the outdated trig functions. How do we guess the values of "$\tan$", "$\cot$", "$\sec$", and "$\csc$" from this picture? Is it respectively the distances $$\rho (A,E),\quad\rho (A,F),\quad\rho (O,E),\quad\rho (O,F)$$

Comment: Why do you want to guess it? Just apply similarity ratios to different triangles and keep in mind that $OA = OD = 1$

Comment: We don't "guess the values [...] from the picture", we (well, *some*, like myself) actually *define* the values from the picture (at least in the first quadrant), and we derive identity relations using properties of right and similar triangles. For instance, $|AE|$ *is* $\tan\theta$ by declaration, but by comparing $\triangle OAE$ to $\triangle OCA$ we find that $|AE|/|OA| = |AC|/|CO|$ ... which is to say, $\tan / 1 = \sin/\cos$. You may find my Bloog post & PDF helpful in understanding the wealth of info in the figure: http://dlnds.com/bloog/almost-everything-you-need-to-remember-about-trig/

Comment: Well I declare the trig functions to be power series, @Blue.

Comment: @George: Interestingly, the power series for four of the six trig functions can be interpreted geometrically: http://dlnds.com/bloog/the-geometry-of-the-power-series-for-trig-functions/  (I'm still searching for the corresponding figures for cosecant and cotangent.)